# 翻訳の誤り: [画像]ボタンのヘルプのサンプルが動作しない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, markdown

編集ヘルプで使える`画像`ボタンで出てくる説明ですが、""を「」に置き換えてしまっているため、サンプルが動作しません。

```
画像はリンクとほぼ同じですが、前に感嘆符を挿入します:
  ![気ぜわしい猫](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)
  ![2 人の操り人形][1]

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg「ツールチップ」
角かっこに囲まれた単号は代替テキストで、ブラウザーが 画像を表示できない場合に表示されます。画面表示ソフトウェアにとって意味のある代替テキストを 含めてください。
```

正しくは例えばこうなると思います (also typo: 単号→単語)。

```
  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg "ツールチップ"
ダブルクォートに囲まれた単語は代替テキストで、ブラウザーが 画像を表示できない場合に表示されます。画面表示ソフトウェアにとって意味のある代替テキストを 含めてください。
```

**Edit**: うまく言葉で説明できずすみません。スクリーンショットを載せます。 CSSでいうと `#mdhelp-images-1579` というIDの要素でした。

[image: Where the text is]

Comment: 記事へのリンクを追加してくれますか？[Markdown または HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定する方法は?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)になかったみたいですので、どこの記事を教えてくれたら、直します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`![気ぜわしい猫](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg) ![2 人の操り人形][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNZ1j.jpg "ツールチップ"`

に直しましたため、次回のビルドから書きになります：

[image: 気ぜわしい猫](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg) ![2 人の操り人形]

（単号→単語も直しました）